# Which usage of German is correct?

Tags: grammar

1. Ich habe deine schöne Tochter, die an der Uni studiert jetzt, gesehen.
2. Ich habe deine schöne Tochter gesehen, die an der Uni studiert jetzt.
3. Ich habe deine an der Uni studiert jetzt schöne Tochter gesehen.

Normally I will use the first two usages to express, but still unclear which one is correct, recently I read some German books and find that German can also be used like the third sentence. Which one is right or all three are acceptable?

Comment: None of your examples is correct, although #1 and #2 are close. What is "ich habe deine Tochter gelesen" (I read your daughter) supposed to mean anyway?

Comment: All three are ungrammatical. In addition to being nonsensical, as you can't read a daughter. Also, all three are punctuated incorrectly. And finally, it's *German*, with a capital *G*.

Comment: Sorry for the silly mistakes i made in the sentences.

Comment: Write "die *jetzt* an der Uni studiert" in #1 and #2. But your main concern seems to be #3. Can you better explain why do you think it is correct (which it isn't)? Maybe you can quote some examples from your book that lead you to this version.

Answer (score 5):

Correct would be:

1. Ich habe deine schöne Tochter, die **jetzt** an der Uni studiert, gesehen.
2. Ich habe deine schöne Tochter gesehen, die **jetzt** an der Uni studiert.
3. Ich habe deine jetzt an der Uni studierende schöne Tochter gesehen. (Technically correct, but incredibly stilted.)

Comment: You mean that the first two sentences are both correct?

Comment: @tachibana... Ingmar's are, yours are not.

Answer (score 2):

First off, all your sentence had the same minor error of putting *jetzt* at the wrong position. As shown in the answer of Ingmar, you can easily fix sentence one and two.

I'd like to elaborate a bit on the third sentence, which your main concern seems to be. Besides the position of *jetzt*, there's a second error.

The relative clause (*die jetzt an der Uni studiert*) can be used as an adjectival phrase, if slightly modified. You already correctly figured out where to put the adjectival phrase:

> Ich habe deine [adjectival phrase] schöne Tochter gesehen.

All you need to do (and this is the second error) is using the present participle (Partizip I) of *studieren*. And, of course, inflect it.

> Ich habe deine [jetzt an der Uni studierende] schöne Tochter gesehen.